# Data augmentation: recuperate the transformed and original images alongside

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am working with MNIST images and I want to perform some data augmentation techniques using Keras `ImageDataGenerator`.

I m wondering if I can get the original images alongside with the transformed ones.
Here is the code so far. Actually, I don't know how to recuperate the original images corresponding to the transformed ones.

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def load_mnist():
    # the data, shuffled and split between train and test sets
    from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
    x = np.concatenate((x_train, x_test))
    y = np.concatenate((y_train, y_test))
    x = x.reshape([-1, 28, 28, 1]) / 255.0
    print('MNIST samples', x.shape)
    return x, y

def show_images(X_original, X_transformed, nb_images=50, img_h=28, img_w=28):
        plt.figure(figsize=(40, 4))
        for i in range(nb_images):
                # display original
                ax = plt.subplot(2, nb_images, i + 1)
                plt.imshow(X_original[i].reshape(28, 28))
                plt.gray()
                ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
                ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

                # display reconstruction
                ax = plt.subplot(2, nb_images, i + 1 + nb_images)
                plt.imshow(X_transformed[i].reshape(28, 28))
                plt.gray()
                ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
                ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
        plt.show()

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(width_shift_range=0.1, height_shift_range=0.1, rotation_range=10, zoom_range=[0.8, 1.2])
X, Y = load_mnist()
gen0 = datagen.flow(X, Y, shuffle=True, batch_size=256)
X1, Y1 = gen0.next()
show_images(X_original=?, X_transformed=X1, nb_images=50, img_h=28, img_w=28)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain the original images alongside with the transformed ones you can instantiate a new `ImageDataGenerator` without any arguments, and when using the respective `flow` for each `ImageDataGenerator` pass the same seed for both functions.

```py
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def load_mnist():
    # the data, shuffled and split between train and test sets
    ...
    return x, y

def show_images(X_original, X_transformed, nb_images=50, img_h=28, img_w=28):
        plt.figure(figsize=(40, 4))
        for i in range(nb_images):
            ...
            ...
        plt.show()

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(width_shift_range=0.4, height_shift_range=0.4,\
                             rotation_range=50, zoom_range=[0.8, 1.2])

datagen_original = ImageDataGenerator() # new generator

X, Y = load_mnist()

gen0 = datagen.flow(X, Y, shuffle=True, batch_size=256, seed=42) # same seed here
gen1 = datagen_original.flow(X, Y, shuffle=True, batch_size=256, seed=42)  # and here

X1, Y1 = gen0.next()
X1_original, Y1_original = gen1.next()

show_images(X_original=X1_original, X_transformed=X1, nb_images=50, img_h=28, img_w=28)
```

[image]